# How pop function is working inside the forloop?

Tags: javascript

```
var fruits = ["Mango", "Pappaya", "Banana", "Orange", "Grapes"];
fruits.push("Kiwi");

for(let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
    console.log(fruits[i]);
    fruits.pop()
}
```

**Output:**
Mango
Pappaya
Banana

Here i dont know how pop() is working. can anyone please explain it for me?

Comment: *"Here i dont know how pop() is working. can anyone please explain it for me?"* [The documentation can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) Did you read it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `fruits`array has a specific length, when [you `pop` an element from it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) that length reduces by one. So `fruits.length` in your loop will change.

The final `pop` will make the array length `3`, and the next iteration "`i`" `3` which is where the loop ends because the condition has been met (`i < fruits.length`).

You can see what happens if you log the various variables.

```js
const fruits = ['Mango', 'Pappaya', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grapes'];

fruits.push('Kiwi');

for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Item: ${fruits[i]}, i: ${i}, Array length: ${fruits.length}, i < fruits.length: ${i < fruits.length}`);
  fruits.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an array

```
var arr = [ 'a','b','c' ];
```

arr.push('d') will add d as the last element of the array. so,

```
arr.push('d')
console.log(arr)
output = [ 'a','b','c', 'd' ]
```

arr.pop() does the opposite and removes the last element. if we arr.pop() on the initial array we get

```
arr.pop()
console.log(arr)
output = [ 'a','b' ]
```